# Website signaled as containing malware

Tags: malware, site-maintenance

I've got a nasty problem with one of our websites. It has been signaled to us by Google and other agencies that it contains malware. We weren't able to understand how to cope with the problem.

Could anyone drive us in the right direction?

UPDATE:

I used google webmaster tools to review the suspicious website. And now it says it's ok! Even if I didn't change anything! How could it be? false alarm?

UPDATE 2:

The site looks infected again...

Comment: Once infected the malware can create rogue php files which are the most difficult to track down. New database entries and more. Functions are often hidden to look like harmless parts of your application. Without access to your site even cleaning your html / php files of typical infections may not completely clean your system. If you need help click my name to go to my profile then contact us through our website.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two steps you need to take.

First, you have to secure your website.
Then you have to go into damage control and try to restore your website's ranking in the search engines.

To secure your website you need to start by changing ALL passwords - particularly ftp but also change anything that requires a password in order to access. Then you should run a scan for trojans and other viruses to make sure nothing is infecting the server. Next you need to check your files and webpage code to make sure that nothing malicious has been added by a hacker.If you have a large site then this will be time consuming but it needs to be done.

[Removing Malware & Securing your website](http://www.stopbadware.org/home/security)

[Google's Advice for your Situation](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2008/04/my-sites-been-hacked-now-what.html)

After all this is completed and you are sure that your site is malware free - you need to restore your website in google's ranking and Bing and the other search engines.

This website will help with that.

[Google Webmaster Central Blog Entry](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2008/08/hey-google-i-no-longer-have-badware.html)

Remember that once you have completely secured your website, you need to request a review from google through the webmaster tools control panel.

I hope this helps

Comment: how can I run a antivirus on my server?
hwr, don't ask me how but after i ask for a  review from google it showed that everything was ok. Even if I didn't do anything!

Comment: @Bakaburg How you add run some-anti-virus software is entirely dependent on your hosting setup. If it's linux/windows, what access you have to the server, whether it's dedicated or shared hositng etc. The best place to start if you're still concerned about it is to speak to your hosting providers. However, the main concern is that someone has changed your website's code to make it malicious rather than infected the server itself - so I'd check the code first.

Comment: i checked the rendered pages sorcecode and it looks ok. If they put something strange in the joomla installation it will be impossible to find!